# MySQL SELECT JOIN WHERE ORDER BY performance

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having two tables that are growing and slowly the queries that where always performing nice, don't perform so quick anymore.

I'm having two tables:

```
# Accounts table
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

# Orders table
CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

See [SQLFiddle for full example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3809/2) with data.

**The query in question**

```
SELECT 
    o.id,
    a.email
FROM `order` o
JOIN account a ON o.account_id = a.id
WHERE a.email LIKE '%@hotmail.com%'
ORDER BY o.id DESC
LIMIT 2
```

This query is running fast with just a couple of records. But using the `EXPLAIN` feature shows that it searches for all records in the account table, not te limited set of `2`.
[image]

This `ORDER BY o.id DESC` will cause trouble in bigger tables. How can I fix this the best way?

1. Split the query in two queries. First get all matching accounts, and then a second query on `order` with `WHERE o.account_id IN (1, 3, 5) ORDER BY o.id DESC`.
2. Use subqueries (no clue how to).
3. Other options...

I'm open for suggestions on how to handle this kind of queries in bigger datasets.

*Note: I know this question is asked several times, but those questions don't have a answer I can use.*

Comment: The slow bit is the "%..." which (unlike "...%") cannot use an index

Comment: Could you store the domain in a separate column?

Comment: @Strawberry, on my database, running this query with `LIKE '%%'`, without the `ORDER BY` runs in 53ms. Adding the `ORDER BY` brings it down to 8 seconds. So it seems the real pain is in the ordering, not the LIKE. In this example I uses the domain as an example, but I want to be able to search for any part of the e-mailadres.

Comment: Option 1 and 2 you provided are quite vague in my opinion. The reason for 1 is When you run a query you get the matching result by specifying email likelihood. rather than on account_id. So to get account_id you had to still perform your provided query. There are two options so far I think to optimize it: One is to limit your records and implement a pagination, Convert your join into view. so don't always need to create a join overhead

Comment: you can create an index on order.id column to improve the performance

Comment: @Sam id is PRIMARY

Comment: Two questions: 1. Is there an index on field "email"? 2. What is the execution time of the following query? SELECT * FROM (SELECT
    o.id,
    a.email
FROM `order` o
JOIN account a ON o.account_id = a.id
WHERE a.email LIKE '%@hotmail.com%' LIMIT 2)
ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: @RWC It's irrelevant. '%...' cannot use an index.

Comment: never use `%` on a large table, in production. this design is flawed.

Comment: @Strawberry: You are right. Postgres does ;-)

Comment: @user2914191, how would you search for a part of a string?
Also trying all suggestions, working on it.

Comment: @user2914191: That has nothing to do with design.

Comment: @RWC I don't know Postgres at all, but are you sure?

Comment: @strawberry: quite.

Comment: @Timo002 its unclear what youre trying to do. are you trying to search for domain, or a substring in general? if you just need to search for domain, make another field for domain and index it

Comment: @user2914191, searching for a substring in a string.

Comment: @Timo002 if you have the value for `account_id` you need to add that part to the `WHERE` section of your query. `WHERE a.id = X AND a.email LIKE '%@hotmail.com%'` then it will use the index. otherwise you might need fulltext index or something else

Comment: @RWC, the query you mentioned LIMITS before it ORDERS. But I first need to order the whole set and then LIMIT it. So it doesn't work in my case. Btw, it runs in 153ms, both tables have almost 1 million records.

Comment: @Timo002: Well move it      SELECT * FROM (SELECT o.id, a.email FROM order o JOIN account a ON o.account_id = a.id WHERE a.email LIKE '%@hotmail.com%' ) LIMIT 2ORDER BY id DESC

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT 
o.id,
a.email
FROM `order` o
JOIN (SELECT id, email 
FROM account 
WHERE email LIKE '%@hotmail.com%') a ON o.account_id = a.id
ORDER BY o.id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to 'trick' MySQL into delaying the lookups with something like this (untested):

```
SELECT x.id
     , x.email
  FROM    
     ( SELECT o.id
            , a.email
         FROM `order` o
         JOIN account a 
           ON o.account_id = a.id
        WHERE a.email LIKE '%@hotmail.com%'
        ORDER 
           BY o.id DESC
        LIMIT 2
     ) x
  JOIN `order` y
    ON y.id = x.id
 ORDER 
    BY y.id;
```

Comment: This isn't any faster. The subquery still has the `order by` that hits the performance.